# Atribuir um valor ao ponteiro e multiplicar (diretamente)

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro

Como eu faço para multiplicar o ponteiro assim que eu assumo um valor a ele?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>


int main (void) {

    int a,*b,*c,*d;

    printf ("\nInforme um valor: ");
    scanf ("%i",&a);

    b = &a; // Como fazer a multiplicação aqui, logo que eu assumo o valor do ponteiro ?
    c = &a;
    d = &a;

    printf("\n%i\n%i\n%i\n",*b*2,*c*3,*d*4); // Assim a legibilidade do código vai ficar ruim com muitos valores

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que você quer multiplicar?

Comment: No caso eu preciso mostrar o dobro, triplo e quádruplo do número digitado pelo usuário ( isso deve ser feito com ponteiros ) !

Comment: Pra mim parece certo. Se tem algum outro objetivo, precisa colocar na pergunta.

Comment: Hm, então não tem como multiplicar diretamente quando se passa um valor ao ponteiro não ?

Comment: Se quer fazer algo diferente, precisa demonstrar o que é.

Comment: Okay, obrigado pela atenção ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As variáveis `b` , `c` e `d` são tipos ponteiros, portanto lá existirá endereços de memória. Você não quer multiplicar o endereço, só quer fazer a operação com o valor. A primeira operação é inicializar a variável com um ponteiro para algum lugar.

O que pode fazer é criar 3 variáveis auxiliares com os valores multiplicados e apontar cada uma dessas variáveis do código para as auxiliares. Bem pior, né?

Depois que fizer a inicialização apontando para a mesma variável pode criar outras 3 auxiliares para guardar a multiplicação nelas. Não parece ser necessário.

Parece um exercício simples e está correto. Se não for isso precisaria ter mais detalhes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu queria multiplicar o valor que estou passando  ( &a ) por dois e guardar no ponteiro, mas entendi que para isso eu preciso de uma variável auxiliar ... obrigado pela explicação ! (:

Answer (score 1):

`&a` não é um valor - é  o endereço onde está o valor que foi digitado no scanf - o mesmo endereço da sua variável "a". Cada endereço só pode ter um valor - então mesmo que alguma ginástica você multiplique o valor que está em `&a` esse novo valor multiplicado será o número naquela posição de memória - um único número para as variáveis "a", "*b", "*c" e "*d".

Ou seja, mesmo que você faça em mais de uma linha - algo como:

```
...
b = &a;
*b *= 2;
...
```

Ao imprimir

```
printf("\n%i\n%i\n%i\n",*b,*c,*d);
```

Você vai ver o mesmo número impresso 3 vezes.

Não dá par saber qual o seu objetivo final, mas para esse caso simples, o melhor é usar variáveis normais, e não ponteiros. Se precisar de ponteiros, precisa arranjar endereços de memória independentes para eles, para que possam conter números distintos.

Ademais - erceba que nessa  situação da pergunta, você tem de fato duas cosias distintas para atribuir: uma é o endereço de memória onde estará o conteúdo das suas variáveis de ponteiro (que você tenta reutilizar sempre o mesmo endereço &a) - e outra é o valor numérico que você quer colocar nesse endereço final (o valor de "a" multiplicado por números distintos).
Se você precisa setar dois valores distintos, precisa fazer duas atribuições.

Agora, por exemplo, se você declarar um vetor, em vez de variáveis de ponteiro com nomes diferentes, você estará nuam situação em que já tem os endereços criados e definidos pelo compilador, e só precisa atribuir os valores -

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int a;
    int b[3];

    printf ("\nInforme um valor: ");
    scanf ("%i",&a);

    for(int i=0, *c=b; i<=3; i++, c++) *c = a * (i + 1);

    printf("\n%i\n%i\n%i\n",b[0], b[1], b[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

A linha `for(int i=0, *c=b; i<=3; i++) *c = a * (i + 1);` inicialiaza o `for` coma  variável `i` como de costume  - somente um contador, mas também um ponteiro `c` que aponta para o primeiro elemento do vetor `b`. Quando i é incrementado, a posiçao `c` também é (A linguagem  `C` é esperta para ponteiros - `c++`  no caso vai avançar não um byte, mas o tamanho do tipo de dado `int` bytes - e apontar certinho para o próximo elemento do vetor `b`).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num = 5;
    int *ptr = &num;

    *ptr *= 2;

    printf("O valor de num é: %d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Neste exemplo, o ponteiro `ptr` é inicializado com o endereço de `num`. Em seguida, o operador de multiplicação `*` é usado para multiplicar o valor apontado por `ptr` por `2`. Finalmente, o resultado é exibido com a função `printf()`.

A saída deste programa será:

```
O valor de num é: 10
```